# How to access to `primordials` object in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node.js and analyzing its source code. I notice Node.js invokes `primordials` many times in its source code. However, I do not know the implementation of `primordials`. After reading the file `lib/internal/per_context/primordials.js`, I find out some of properties of `primordials`, such as `primordials.Array` and `primordials.ArrayBuffer` are JS builtins:

```
[
  'Array',
  'ArrayBuffer',
  'BigInt',
  'BigInt64Array',
  'BigUint64Array',
  'Boolean',
  'DataView',
  'Date',
  'Error',
  'EvalError',
  'Float32Array',
  'Float64Array',
  'Function',
  'Int16Array',
  'Int32Array',
  'Int8Array',
  'Map',
  'Number',
  'Object',
  'RangeError',
  'ReferenceError',
  'RegExp',
  'Set',
  'String',
  'Symbol',
  'SyntaxError',
  'TypeError',
  'URIError',
  'Uint16Array',
  'Uint32Array',
  'Uint8Array',
  'Uint8ClampedArray',
  'WeakMap',
  'WeakSet',
].forEach((name) => {
  const original = global[name];
  primordials[name] = original;
  copyPropsRenamed(original, primordials, name);
  copyPrototype(original.prototype, primordials, `${name}Prototype`);
});
```

However, I cannot find the implementation of other properties of `primordials`, such as `primordials.FunctionPrototypeCall` and `primordials.ObjectDefineProperty`.
In order to understand all the properties of `primordials`, I want to access to `primordials` after compiling of Node.js's source code. Is there any method to access to `primordials`? Thx.

Comment: No, there's not. But you can just copy the above code into your own module, to create your own `primordials` object.

Comment: @Bergi Hi, consider I have the source code of Node.js, is there any special method to access to `primordials` object?

Comment: Access it from where? If you compile nodejs yourself, you can of course just add `global.whynotwhatcouldgowrong = primordials;` to the file

Comment: Did you figure it out yet? What about other code like `require('internal/modules/cjs/helpers')`, I cannot get it to work aswell.

Answer (score 1):

`primordials` are the internal name for any built-in JS data types, you can access them from any JS code that you run with Node.js because these are global entities. e.g. if you have `index.js` file you can just call `new Array` or any other primordial and then run it with `node ./index.js`

Also as far as I know in you are writing some code in `lib` folder here you would need to access these in a special manner, but I think you are just wring the JS code so you don't care about it.

Most of these types come from `V8` engine.

Comment: Some built-in JS data types, e.g., `Array` can be accessed from any JS code, while some data types are not, e.g., `primordials.FunctionPrototypeCall` and `primordials.ObjectDefineProperty`.  I also want to access to primordials.FunctionPrototypeCall` and `primordials.ObjectDefineProperty`. More info: `primordials.FunctionPrototypeCall` and `primordials.ObjectDefineProperty` are invoked in file `lib/interval/fs.js`.

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake: `primordials.FunctionPrototypeCall` and `primordials.ObjectDefineProperty` are invoked in file l`ib/interval/fs/watchers.js`

Comment: It is because Node.js does not expose them to end-users, as they are internal types, I believe. If you want to have access to these types you need to write the code in the `internal` folder, though I doubt that you need to do that unless you are a Node.js contributor.

Comment: Most of these "types" are accessed in more JS native way, e.g. calling `ObjectDefineProperty` is the same as `Object.defineProperty` call.